# React native display layout

Tags: android-layout, view, react-native

Please can you help me? Im trying to do layout like this, from begining there will be camera but if I click button driving info it will be replaced with that, here is the layout I want and here is my code. Right now all the touchablehighlits(buttons) are overlaying, + camera window should be livestream from raspberry pi camera but right now Im focusing just on layout.

```
const MainScreen = () => {
return(
<View>
  <View style={{flex: 33, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-start', position: 'relative'}}>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} >
        <Text style={styles.txt}> CAMERA </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight> 
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 33, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', position: 'relative'}}>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} >
        <Text style={styles.txt}> Lane assistant </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} >
        <Text style={styles.txt}> disconnect </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} >
        <Text style={styles.txt}> driving info </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 33, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', position: 'relative'}}>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} >
        <Text style={styles.txt}>- </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} >
        <Text style={styles.txt}> cruise control </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} >
        <Text style={styles.txt}>+ </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>

</View>
);
```

}

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 button:{
  justifyContent: 'space-between',

},
txt:{
  fontSize: 30,
}
```

});

[image]

Comment: This is way too general, please specify what is causing trouble, what is happening vs the expected. Mention what you have tried, etc.

Comment: I want to have 3 rows, first with camera/driving info, second and third with touchablehighlight(buttons) for each thing. Im having trouble placing them on screen based on layout on photo. right now all "buttons" are overlaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fine:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={styles.topContainer}>
    <TouchableHighlight  >
        <Text> CAMERA </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight> 
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={styles.buttonRowContainer}>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.touchableContainer} >
        <Text > Lane assistant </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.touchableContainer} >
        <Text>disconnect </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.touchableContainer} >
        <Text  > driving info </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.buttonRowContainer}>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.touchableContainer} >
        <Text  >- </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.touchableContainer} >
        <Text  > cruise control </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight style={styles.touchableContainer} >
        <Text >+ </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
  </View>
</View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonRowContainer: {
flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  touchableContainer: {
    flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'
  },
  topContainer: {
    flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'
  }
})
```

I'm going to explain how flex works. If you only have one element with `flex: 1` it will take all the screen space. This is usually done when you have a View which will contain all the other elements. If we want to divide the screen by two, we have to define 2 components with `flex: 1`

```
 - Main -> flex: 1
   - Children 1 -> flex: 1
   - Children 2 -> flex: 1
```

Children 1 will take 50% of the screen size as well as Children 2. If we want children 1 to take 66% of the screen we simply add `flex: 2`. Is like telling React "hey, I want you to divide the screen in 3 equal parts, Children 1 takes 2 portions of the screen when Children 2 only takes 1". Remember this will only work if your parent has set flex.